# How to assign class based on regexp match (sorting in perl)

Tags: regex, perl, sorting

I am reading from file. Based on value in one column, I want to assign my own class/tag to it.

These regexps:

'LTR*','MLT*','MST*' ... 
 belong to the class HERV.

'Charlie*','Looper*' ... 
belong to the class DNA

Right now I have two arrays, one with regexps and one with respective classes:

```
 my @array = map { qr{$_} } ('Alu*', 'HERV*', 'Charlie*' ...
 my @classes = ('Alu', 'HERV', 'DNA', 'LINE' ...
```

So that I know that if my line matches Charlie*, it belongs to the class DNA.

To sum it up, for every line of the file I am looping the whole array and looking for match:

```
for my $i (0 .. $#array) {

        if ($type =~ m/$array[$i]/) { 
                       my $class=$classes[$i];
        }

}
```

Of course, this is not too clever. It would be much better to say: "this group of regexps belongs to this class" which suggests use of hash.

However, I consider it quite inconvenient to loop all lines, than all keys of hashmap and then all values of certain keys and, when there is a match, use the key as the resulting class/tag. Is this good solution or not?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
my %re = (
       HERV=>qr/LTR|MLT|MST/,
       DNA=> qr/Charlie|Looper/
   );
my $class;
for (keys %re) {
    $class = $_, last if ($type =~ $re{$_});
}
```

This will save you some regex compilation and one loop.

Answer (score 0):

The CPAN module [Text::Prefix::XS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Prefix-XS/) appears to do what you want:  determine which if any of a list of prefixes match a given text.  I have not used the module, but from what I can tell you would do something like:

```
my %prefix2class = ( LTR => 'HERV',
                     MLV => 'HERV',
                     ...
                     Charlie => 'DNA' );

my $search = prefix_search_create( keys %prefix2class );

# ... now, for a given $type, no need to loop ...
my $pfx = prefix_search($search, $type);
my $class = $prefix2class{$pfx};
```

(Note:  Your regexes look to me like shell-style/fnmatch-style patterns dubiously compiled as regexes, and from this I infer that you actually want simple prefix matching.  Otherwise, the regex `/Charlie*/`, for example, would match `Charli`, `Charlieeee`, `fooCharliebar`, and so on — that seems unlikely to be representative of your *"value in one column"*.)

Comment: Thank you. I have already used perreal approach, but I will keep in mind that this exists for future. And yes, it may be weird, but in my context (biology) I really want to match all lines with Charlie :-) It's part of the name of transposable element http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposable_element